# Add label to group pricing

Tags: price

Im looking at adding a simple label to show up on products when group pricing is connected to a product (user is logged in). Something as simple as this (https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/add-product-labels/) but i want it to automatically show up.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Not yet. Note sure where to start. Only new at magento

Comment: Ok, I'm in the train on my phone so let me see what I can find when I'm on my laptop later on :)

Comment: Hi Sander. Did you get a chance to look at this? thanks.